# SCNShadable not animating

Tags: swift, scenekit, fragment-shader

UPDATED:

I've got a basic SceneKit rendering a box.

I'm trying to get a kind of wavy effect on the sides using a simple fragment shader I found online.

The shader setup follows the guidelines but no effects happen.

```swift
        let box = SCNBox(width: 250, height: 250, length: 250, chamferRadius: 0)

        let greenMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        greenMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        greenMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        let redMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        redMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        redMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        let blueMaterial  = SCNMaterial()
        blueMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        blueMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        let yellowMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        yellowMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        yellowMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        let purpleMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        purpleMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        purpleMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

        let whiteMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        whiteMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "water_seamless_day")
        whiteMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse   = true

        box.materials =  [greenMaterial,
                          redMaterial,
                          blueMaterial,
                          yellowMaterial,
                          purpleMaterial,
                          whiteMaterial]

        box.firstMaterial?.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "waterNormal.png")

        let shaders = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.fragment : "// Elapsed time in seconds            float waterSpeed = u_time * -0.1;// Texture coordinates that will be used to sample the normal map vec2 uvs = _surface.normalTexcoord; uvs.x *= 2;// Sample the normal map vec3 tn = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x, uvs.y + waterSpeed)).xyz; // The texture stores values in the [0, 1] range// Express the coordinates of the normal vector in the [-1, +1] range tn = tn * 2 - 1; // Sample the normal map again, using the `waterSpeed` offset this time // in order to produce the animation effect vec3 tn2 = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x + 0.35 , uvs.y + 0.35 + (waterSpeed * 1.3))).xyz; tn2 = tn2 * 2 - 1;  // Combine the two normals (static and animated) to produce a richer (more complex and less uniform) effect  vec3 rn = (tn + tn2) * 0.5;// Normals in the normal map are expressed in tangent space // Convert them to object space and override the surface normal to simulate wavelets mat3 ts = mat3(_surface.tangent, _surface.bitangent, _surface.geometryNormal); _surface.normal = normalize(ts * rn);"  , SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.surface : "float waterSpeed = u_time * -0.1;vec2 uvs = _surface.normalTexcoord;uvs.x *= 2;vec3 tn = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x, uvs.y + waterSpeed)).xyz;tn = tn * 2 - 1;vec3 tn2 = texture2D(u_normalTexture, vec2(uvs.x + 0.35 , uvs.y + 0.35 + (waterSpeed * 1.3))).xyz;tn2 = tn2 * 2 - 1;vec3 rn = (tn + tn2) * 0.5;mat3 ts = mat3(_surface.tangent, _surface.bitangent, _surface.geometryNormal);_surface.normal = normalize(ts * rn);"]

        box.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = shaders

        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)

        self.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

        self.sceneKitView?.rendersContinuously = true
```

EDITED with new shader code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shader code is absolutely not a SceneKit shader modifier. There's a snippet in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) that you posted that shows the correct structure.

Comment: Oh. Sorry.  Does that mean I've got everything else right, just not the code in the Shader file?

Comment: Updated with reference code from Apple. Still nothing moving.